# Find the given number is armstrong Number or not if Number is armstrong print 0 and if not a armstron print 1

Tags: java

**Trying Code as follows But it not working as per requirement  printing 0 if armstrong number and 1 if not armstrong number**
*Suggest correction for implementing this program*

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Example {
   public static boolean solution(int N) {
       boolean isNumber = false;
       @SuppressWarnings("unused")
       int i=1;
       int c=0,a,temp;
       temp=N;
       while(N>0) {
           a=N%10;
           N=N/10;
           c=c+(a*a*a);
       }
       if(temp==c) {
           i = isNumber ? 1 : 0;
       }
       System.out.println(isNumber);
       return isNumber;
   }
}
class Arm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = s.nextInt();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Example ex= new Example();
        Example.solution(N);
    }
}
```

Comment: Time to fire up your debugger.

Comment: man that code is difficult to read :-) couldn't resist rewriting it https://pastebin.com/Sb73jWwc (see existing answers for the bugfix)

Comment: Note: your algorithm is only valid for 3 digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

@Sanjyukta you have not assigned `isNumber=true` if the number is armstrong, so everytime it will return `false` and `0` and It will not update the value of `i` and `isNumber`.
Below code will update the `isNumber` and `i` values.

```
  if (temp == c) {
            isNumber = true;
            i = isNumber ? 0 : 1;
        }
        System.out.println(isNumber + "\t" + i);
```

Comment: **printing 0 if armstrong number and 1 if not armstrong number**

Comment: Am I get something wrong? Accoring to discreption, when it's Amstrong Number, shouldn't  assign i = 0?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer of my question: It is possible by using Ternary operator**

```
public static void solution(int N)
{
 int c=0,a,temp;
 temp=N;
 while(N>0)
  {
      a=N%10;
      N=N/10;
      c=c+(a*a*a);
  }
 if(temp == c)
  {
      boolean b = true;
      c = (b) ? 1 : 0;
  }
 else
  {
     boolean b = false;
     c = (b) ? 1 : 0;
  }
   System.out.println(c);
}

class Arm
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       @SuppressWarnings("resource")
       Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
       int N = s.nextInt();
       @SuppressWarnings("unused")
       Example ex= new Example();
       ex.solution(N);
   }
 }
```

Comment: not just `System.out.println((temp == c) ? 1 : 0);`  (after the while block)? and wrong answre for e.g. `2` which also is an Armstrong Number (based on Wikipedia)